# Função para enviar dados para o banco após um tempo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou precisado de uma função que depois de 1 minuto e 30 segundos seja enviado os dados para o banco de dados. Após muita pesquisa não consegui fazer isto de forma dinâmica consigo fazer ele com uma `div` aparecendo após este tempo, mas queria que não seja necessário o usuário clicar para funcionar.

Alguém sabe como fazer esta façanha ?

Comment: Provavelmente você está procurando por `setInterval`. Mas, depois de 1 minuto e 30 segundos com relação a quê? Algum clique do botão, outro evento..

Comment: bom o usuário ira assistir um vídeo e após 1 minuto e 30 segundos vendo o vídeo será enviado uma função que adicionara 1 ponto para este usuário que poderá depois usar estes pontos para outras coisas

Answer (score 1):

para agendar uma execução, você pode utilizar o `window.setTimeout`, para enviar os dados para o servidor, você pode utilizar o `XMLHttpRequest` ou o `$.ajax`.

```
var dados = { prop1: "Hello", prop2: "World" };
var tempo = 90 * 1000;
window.setTimeout(function () {
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.open("POST", urlParaSalvarOsDados, true);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
        console.log("Dados enviados com sucesso");
      } else {
        console.log("Erro no envio dos dados");
      }
    }
  });
  httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(dados))
}, tempo);
```